# lazy var NSFetchedResultsController producing error in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I just migrated my project to Swift 3 and am stuck on an error for my lazy instantiated NSFetchResultController. I use this method here :

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/05/displaying-data-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift/

My current code

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {

    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "company", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor]

    self.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: self.fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil)

    frc.delegate = self

    return frc
}()
```

It produces 2 errors as shown below

[image]

Is this method no longer possible under Swift 3? I tried adding `() -> <<error type>> in` as suggested by Xcode but failed to produce the correct results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The suggested `() -> <<error type>>` is misleading.

In Swift 3 `NSFetchedResultsController` has become a generic type.
You have to initialize it:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
...
}()
```

as well as `NSFetchRequest`

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MyEntity")
```

---

If you are using a subclass of `NSManagedObject` – which is recommended – you can use the subclass type for being more specific

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<MyEntity> = {
....
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>(entityName: "MyEntity")
```

The huge benefit is you get rid of all type casts using `fetch`, `insert` etc.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. On a side note that you don't need to answer. Is there any good documentation about subsclassing NSManagedObject?

Comment: Actually the most comprehensive documentation is the Apple documentation.

Comment: @vadian Must it always be initialized as `lazy`? Let's say I wanted to change key paths of a fetch request on the same view controller.

Comment: `lazy` just means that the controller is initialized not until it's accessed the first time. As the controller is mutable you can change its properties or even assign a new instance at any time.

Comment: Cool...so if I set it to something else after it's initialized, it's not going to grab the values within the lazy initializer?

Comment: Yes, the closure is only called once.

Comment: Brilliant...I though that was the case, but before I refactored a bunch of stuff I wanted to make sure it was not for naught.