# Ios Swift3 : lazy var fetchrequestcontroller showing an error

Tags: ios, core-data, controller, swift3, fetch

I was using a lazy var in table view controller to get the data from CoreData. It was working good in swift2. But When I upgraded to Swift3, Its showing an error as below. Kindly help me to change for Swift3

> Error : Cannot convert value of type 'Error' to specified type 'NSFetchedResultsController'

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSfetchedResultsController =
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EvtIvtTbl")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "bym_kol", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    let fetchedResultsController = NSfetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                     managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext,
                                                     sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                     cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Comment: have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816877/lazy-var-nsfetchedresultscontroller-producing-error-in-swift-3-0

Comment: All of your variables should be in `camelCase`. For readability, you should give your local variables more generic names, too. I cleaned it up a bit so you can see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3.0, `NSFetchedResultsController` and `NSFetchRequest` want type parameters.  Assuming that `EvtIvtTbl` is your `NSManagedObject` subclass, your code should look like this:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<EvtIvtTbl> = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<EvtIvtTbl>(entityName: "EvtIvtTbl")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "bym_kol", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<EvtIvtTbl>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                 managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext,
                                                 sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                 cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```